# Calculations ignored on a fresh MiKTeX install

Tags: miktex

On a fresh MiKTeX 2.9 install, previously working piece of code

```
\begin{tabular}{>{}p{9em}p{\linewidth-12em}}
```

is not working anymore — -12em is being outputted in table row fields instead of being calculated. What have I missed?

Comment: For that to work the `calc` package is necessary. It may have happened that a package used to load it and doesn't now in a more recent version.

Comment: expl3 has removed the loading of `calc` recently.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You forgot

```
\usepackage{calc}
```

, which supports infix arithmetic in LaTeX.

[Package description](http://ctan.org/pkg/calc)